# Redshift Workload Managment: Memory

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to setup Redshift Workload Management to handle

- 50% ETL
- 30% Tableau Rpts
- 20% adhoc queries.

I'm wondering what happens to un-allocated memory as my ETL only runs at night?

What happens to the 50% memory my ETL queue is allocated for in the day time when that queue is idle?

I read the Redshift documentation and it only says

> Any unallocated memory is managed by Amazon Redshift

and is not descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Workload Management (WLM) is a way of dividing available memory amongst queues.

If you allocate 50% to the ETL queue and you are not running any ETL jobs, then you have wasted 50% of the cluster's memory for that period of time.

A better approach might be to create separate queues based upon the workload. For example:

- One queue for small, quick queries (eg used on real-time Dashboards)
- Another queue for larger queries

Amazon Redshift is getting 'smarter' at figuring out how to prioritize queries but you can certainly tweak it with thoughtful use of WLM.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I want to setup my ETL processes to not use the default queue. What would be a good way to determine how much memory to allocate to that queue?

Comment: The only way to know how many queues and how much memory to assign is to try various different settings, measure the results and then keep adjusting. You want to give users the feeling that the system is running fast (eg by having a separate queue for small requests). Large jobs can also [request multiple slots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_wlm_query_slot_count.html) via `wlm_query_slot_count` settings on a specific query.